# How to know which mod_ssl version will work with which httpd Version (Incase I have no-ssl version installed initially)?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I had httpd 2.2.25 no-ssl installed on my server, to enable ssl I followed the following -

1. Installed OpenSSL from [here](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip&can=2&q=).
2. Generated self-signed certificate (server.crt and server.key).
3. Edited httpd-ssl.conf and httpd.conf to include .crt and .key files as well as mod_ssl.so from modules.
4. Placed mod_ssl.so in the modules folder of apache.I used mod_ssl.so from various different sources available on the internet (also from the modules folder of a httpd 2.2.25 ssl version, but none seemed to work)
5. On restarting httpd it gave this error everytime: 
   **httpd.exe Syntax error in line 123 c:/xyz/apache/conf/httpd.conf can not load c:/xyz/apache/modules/mod_ssl.so into server. The specified module can not found.**

At last when nothing worked, I had to go with a new httpd installation with ssl.

This seems like some kind of version miss-match to me, but not sure if it is mod_ssl.so OR libeay32.dll OR ssleay32.dll causing the problem.

How to deal with this next time, I dont want to go with the re-installation everytime ?

Comment: The answer to this question will be found at the Apache HTTP website. Off topic here.

Comment: @EJP I tried [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_compat.html) , but could not find the answer. Please could you help ?